# PHP - break a string to a newline

Tags: php, newline

In PHP, I am creating a long string, like this:

```
$cmd = "scp -P 435 xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxx:/var/backups/db/xxxxxxxxxxxxx{$todayTimestamp}*.sql.gz /var/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/"
```

In order to better display the code on the monitor, I would like to break it to a new line but I dont't want the $cmd variable to contain a new line character.

An easy solution would be:

```
$cmd = "__first_part__ ";
$cmd .= "__second_part__";
```

But I don't like that very much.

I bet there is a better way in PHP.

Does anybody know that, please?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you don't want to use any function, array or anything like that but the only other coding style that comes to mind would be:

```
$cmd = "__first_part__ ".
"__second_part__";
```

its nearly the same, but at least you don't have to use the variable name all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Use an editor with line-wrapping, such as geany, vim, gvim, etc.

Answer (score 0):

U dont't want to use \n for line  break u can use <br />.
$cmd = 'text <br /> test'; In php we have nl2br() function u can also use that.

Comment: That is still adding a line break to a command. The OP doesn't want that to happen. It is for editing purpose that the "wrapping" is required as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

1st:

```
$text = "line one
line two
line three";
```

And another way:

```
$text = "line one".
        "line two".
        "line three";
```

Comment: your first solution would produce "\n" line breaks